# global locks preventing the rest of my code from executing despite no other threads

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

```
def addUser_InHash(username, password, clearanceLvl):
    print("Adding user in hash")
    hashID = 0
    hashString = username + password
    hashIncIndex = 0  # This is used to increment "hashIncrement"
    added = False
    for i in hashString:
        hashID += ord(i)
    hashID = hashID % hashKey
    print(hashID, "hashID in addUser")
    try:
        with open("LoginHashTable.pickle", "rb") as file:
            saved_data = pickle.load(file)
            print("Original")
            print(saved_data)

    except:
        saved_data = {}
    print("File opened")


    while not added:
    # Make this so that it can check for unique usernames, using AND statements, and two variables
        if hashID in saved_data:
            print()
            if hashID == (hashKey - 1):
                hashID = 0
            else:
                hashID += hashIncrement[hashIncIndex]

            if hashIncIndex != 3:
                hashIncIndex += 1  # Increments hashIncrement
            else:
                hashIncIndex = 0
        else:
            print("User doesnt exist, adding to hash table")
            saved_data[hashID] = [username, password]
            print("New Added")
            print(saved_data)
            added = True
    print("Saving updated file addUser_InHash")
    with global_lock:
        print("past global lock")
        with open("LoginHashTable.pickle", "wb") as file:
            pickle.dump(saved_data, file)
            print(saved_data)
            print("Data saved")
```

This python code stops at the "with global_lock" part for some odd reason.
global lock is defined as

```
global_lock = Lock()
```

and my threads are defined as

```
connThread = Thread(target=handler, args=(conn, addr))
```

this is called by another function, and needs to finish so that My client (contacting the server this code is located on) can continue
There are no other threads running at this point as I restart the server every time.

Comment: It won't be possible to debug the problem without seeing the rest of the code.  The output you get when running the program will also be useful.

Comment: The problem is that there is no output. It stops at the global lock